# How to use DynamoDb transactions with Object persistence model in .NET

Tags: .net, amazon-dynamodb

AWS SDK provides [Document model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetSDKMidLevel.html) and [Object persistence model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetSDKHighLevel.html) to use any .NET instance as data for simple CRUD operations.

Is there a way to use any .NET instance in DynamoDb transactions? Can I convert it to [TransactWriteItems](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TransactWriteItems.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

- [DocumentTransactWrite](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/DynamoDBv2/TDocumentTransactWrite.html) (Document)
- [DataModelTransactWrite](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/DynamoDBv2/TDocumentTransactWrite.html) (OPM)

Comment: They have been added 6 days ago. I used not the latest version. Wasted so much time.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ay_F-Y7mERk